# Converting a program into a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, supervisord

I'm trying to convert this program:

**DownloadJetAdvice Edge**

Full installation guide for can be seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxo9ms5xzkcz7yz/JetAdvice%20Edge%20-%20Installation%20Guide%20for%20Raspberry%20Pi%20OS%20v1.1.pdf)

From an installation to a linux machine, into a Docker container.

I need multiple running instances of this, and i've been using Docker alot in my sparetime, and it's finally time to use in my work aswell!

I've got the dockerfile complete (i think) when i build it, it downloads, and installs what it needs to, and the build completes without issues.

However, I can't get the JetAdvice program / services to run!
I've read, that if i want multiple things to run in a container, i should use supervisor, and since the JetEdge program has 3 running services, i'm using that.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

MAINTAINER me

EXPOSE 33322
COPY startup.sh /opt/scripts/startup.sh
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-utils wget libunwind8 icu-devtools supervisor 
RUN mkdir -p -- /var/log/supervisor /opt/print/download /opt/print/edgeinstaller /opt/scripts

RUN wget https://app.jetadvice.com/install/edge/jetadvice-edge-linux-x64.tar -P /opt/print/download && \
    tar -xvf /opt/print/download/jetadvice-edge-linux-x64.tar -C /opt/print/edgeinstaller

RUN chmod +x /opt/print/edgeinstaller/Installer && \
    /opt/print/edgeinstaller/Installer install

RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/JetAdvice/Updater/Updater && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/JetAdvice/EdgeUI/EdgeUi && \
    chmod +x /opt/scripts/startup.sh

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/opt/scripts/startup.sh"]
```

This is my supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:JetAdvice-Edge]
command=/usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge

[program:JetAdvice-Updater]
command=/usr/bin/JetAdvice/Updater/Updater

[program:JetAdvice-Edge-UI]
command=/usr/bin/JetAdvice/EdgeUI/EdgeUi
```

And the startup.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#somethingvariblehere
/usr/bin/supervisord
```

I've tried to run the JetAdvice a bunch of ways, but i can't get the program to run.

For info, this is one of the JedAdvice-Edge.service files:

```
Description=JetAdvice Edge connector service
Wants=network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If i log into my docker container and try to run the service, i get this erroor

```
root@6727e8f42044:/# service JetAdvice-Updater start
JetAdvice-Updater: unrecognized service
```

If i try to run the program directly i get:

```
root@6727e8f42044:/# /usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge
bash: /usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge: Permission denied
root@6727e8f42044:/# ./usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge
bash: ./usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge: Permission denied
```

I tried doing chmod +x on /usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge and then it seems like the program is running for 3 seconds, then nothing happens.

```
root@6727e8f42044:/# chmod +x /usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge
root@6727e8f42044:/# /usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge
root@6727e8f42044:/#
```

I'm not even close to a linux expert, but i can't imagine that what i'm trying to do, can't be done.
So what am i doing wrong, what's the next step?

Working install.json file from the JetEdge team

```
{
  "InstallConfig": {
    "ApiClient": {
      "SignIn": {
        "InstallKey": "prettykeyhere",
        "DcaInstanceID": "prettyidhere"
      },
      "HttpLogging": {
        "MaxSize": 10240,
        "LogHttp": false
      },
      "Proxy": {
        "Address": "",
        "Port": 8080,
        "AutoDetect": true
      }
    },
    "ApiEndpoint": {
      "LoginBaseAddress": "https://auth.eu.edge-api.com",
      "BaseAddress": "https://dr.eu.edge-api.com",
      "ConfigBaseAddress": "https://config.eu.edge-api.com",
      "StayAliveBaseAddress": "https://p.eu.edge-api.com",
      "UpdateBaseAddress": "https://upd.eu.edge-api.com",
      "UiApiBaseAddress": "https://ui.eu.edge-api.com",
      "RangesBaseAddress": "https://ranges.eu.edge-api.com",
      "LoggerBaseAddress": "https://log.eu.edge-api.com",
      "StatusBaseAddress": "https://status.eu.edge-api.com"
    },
    "Installs": [
      {
        "Product": 1,
        "Folder": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetAdvice\\Updater",
        "ServiceName": "JetAdvice-Updater",
        "ServiceExe": "Updater.dll",
        "Version": "0.4.18.0",
        "BuildRID": "win-x86",
        "Oem": 0
      },
      {
        "Product": 10,
        "Folder": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetAdvice\\Edge",
        "ServiceName": "JetAdvice-Edge",
        "ServiceExe": "Edge.dll",
        "Version": "0.4.24.0",
        "BuildRID": "win-x86",
        "Oem": 0
      },
      {
        "Product": 20,
        "Folder": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetAdvice\\EdgeUI",
        "ServiceName": "JetAdvice-Edge-UI",
        "ServiceExe": "EdgeUi.dll",
        "Version": "0.4.1.0",
        "BuildRID": "win-x86",
        "Oem": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the key i generated for testing is:
**4809b732-eb36-413f-8993-bd8d1f2e2942**

EDIT, i've updated the dockerfile, and added the startup.sh script to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly modified your Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

EXPOSE 33322

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-utils wget libunwind8 icu-devtools supervisor 

#RUN apt-get install -y systemctl
#RUN apt-get install -y systemd

RUN mkdir -p -- /var/log/supervisor /opt/print/download /opt/print/edgeinstaller

RUN wget https://app.jetadvice.com/install/edge/jetadvice-edge-linux-x64.tar -P /opt/print/download && \
    tar -xvf /opt/print/download/jetadvice-edge-linux-x64.tar -C /opt/print/edgeinstaller && \
    chmod +x /opt/print/edgeinstaller/Installer && \
    /opt/print/edgeinstaller/Installer install
    
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

I have added this line
`RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/JetAdvice/Edge/Edge` for adding +x to the executable.

Now when I started the container gave me an error and it stop the `supervisord`.
Under `/usr/share/JetAdvice/Edge/LogFiles` you can find the *JetAdvice Edge* logs whitin it this error

> install.json - Install key is missing. (Parameter 'InstallKey')
>
> at
> EF.JA.Edge.Service.Windows.Program.<>c.b__2_3(HostBuilderContext
> hostContext, IServiceCollection services)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()    at
> EF.JA.Edge.Service.Windows.Program.Main(String[] args)

I have found the `install.json` file under `/usr/share/JetAdvice/Edge/Config/Shared`, inside there are the `InstallKey` json field

```
{
  "InstallConfig": {
    "ApiClient": {
      "SignIn": {
        "InstallKey": "",
        "DcaInstanceID": "e5860224-12a6-429e-b931-86c50a7a5900"
      },
[..]
}
```

I found on google this [web site about JetAdvice](https://jetadvice.com/support/download/connector/) where says:

> Download JetAdvice Edge and **generate Install Key**

I don't have an account but I suppose you must generate the key and setup the install.json.

Comment: Wow! that's alot of info!
You're right, i get an account key for each customer, and it should be in the json file! 
I was expecting the program to be accessible from web after install, and then i could type ind the account key there, but if i have to do it another way that's fine aswell!

Ill try the changes you've made, and use a "proper" json file with the account info.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Glad to help you, you can use the [ENV variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) to pass the key to the container but you must write some bash to read the ENV and place to the json. Mark as the answer if it's correct.

Comment: So i got access to generate install keys now, and i've added it in my containter (just installed nano and pasted it for testing) but i don't think it's working yet.

I'm not sure if the install key needs to be present before first launching the program or not.

I've got a working install.json file, and i've edited my first post to contain it. (i got it from the JedEdge support team)

Comment: I would like some help with how to add the installID with the ENV variable.
I was thinking i could have an ENV file with all the different customers Install ID, and call the env in the final docker compose file that i will use to create the containers.

I've also updated the dockerfile and the supervisord.conf file to match your changes and add the 2 other services.

Comment: Create (and copy to image) a `startup.sh` file where you 1. write code to [replace ENV into file](https://zhu45.org/posts/2016/Dec/21/environment-variable-substitution-using-sed/) and 2. launch the `supervisord`. Then replace the CMD with `CMD ['/whatever/startup.sh']`

Comment: Alright, how would a script like that look? :$

Comment: Its too long to explain into comment. Maybe is better for you to copy the `install.json` into your pc, edit it with the correct key and copy to the container when build Dockerfile.

Comment: An alternative way, would be to map the folder or maybe just that file directly to the host of the docker instance, so it's easy to edit the install.json file, and then start the container.

I'll try that when i'm back at work on monday, thanks alot for the advice man!

Comment: Glad to help you. Mark as the answer if you can.

Comment: I got it working now! you can see the result if'd you like here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/equalixer/jetedge

Thanks alot for the help!